# How do I use Netlify's environment variables with vanilla JavaScript?

Tags: javascript, node.js, netlify

I am not using React or Node. I want to use an API key for a small project that I don't want to commit to Github. Netlify has built in [environment variables](https://www.netlify.com/blog/2021/07/05/easy-access-environment-variables/).

You set them up in a name key pair in Netlify something like

SECRET_NAME = secretkey

When the site builds, Node would replace anywhere I used process.env.SECRET_NAME with secretkey.

But I am not using Node, or a build process, so of course when I call `process.env.ENV_VAR_NAME` in my code it fails with the error `Uncaught ReferenceError: process is not defined`

What is the easiest way to utilize Netlify's environment variables with just vanilla Javascript?

Saw this [question which suggests using a Netlify Lambda function](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/57330728/how-to-use-netlify-lambda-functions-to-hide-api-key), but it still uses Node which I am not using.

Comment: To confirm, you realize that the API key will be readable in dev tools?

Comment: Don't. You can't. Just don't. If you're using environment variables to use secrets, your client can see it. If you're just trying to adapt to the environment, not quite either. Just declare some global variables that act as envs.

Comment: Maybe you can write a function that calls the api with the key? https://docs.netlify.com/functions/overview/

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How to use Netlify Lambda Functions to hide API key](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/57330728/how-to-use-netlify-lambda-functions-to-hide-api-key)

Comment: This quick YouTube video may help: https://youtu.be/gWIK_QHyuWs

Comment: @JBallin super close but I think the answer is still using Node which I am not using.

Comment: @code Thanks for the tip. I was eventually going to use them for API secrets. After reading more I get what you are saying. They are still available to the client so not secret.

Comment: @JBallin did not realize that. After reading more, super clear now. Thank you.

Comment: @JoshuaDance Netlify functions need to run on a server. If you use JavaScript to write them - they'll be run in Node.js (see [netlify JS functions docs](https://docs.netlify.com/functions/build-with-javascript/#runtime-settings)).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

## Issue: There are no "secrets" client-side.

It's a common misconception that you can store secrets in React apps...despite my attempts to make this clear in the [docs](https://create-react-app.dev/docs/adding-custom-environment-variables/).

To avoid exposing your API key, you'll need to both store and read the key on a server. This means you'll need to build an app using a server-side framework such as Node.js.

## Recommended Solution: Netlify Function

[Netlify Functions](https://docs.netlify.com/functions/overview/) are a convenient way to create an endpoint within the same repository/deployment.

## Alternative Solution: Separate API

Create a separate API that fetches from the third-party API and returns the data.

## Consider securing your API/function with CORS

You can make it harder (there are ways around this) for other sites to use your API by implementing [CORS](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTTP/CORS) to only allow fetching from your frontend domain.

Answer (score 1):

After more reading, I know 2 things.

1. How to do this. [This video was helpful](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=gWIK_QHyuWs&feature=youtu.be).
2. You should not do this to try and hide API secrets or keys.

While it is true the keys won't be in your source code, the problem is once Netlify replaces the API secrets or keys then the client can see them. Not good.